# Is there a way to use designated initializers to initialize parts of the same array in separate files?

Tags: arrays, c, initialization, c99, extern

I have thousands of "commands" that are all defined in their own files, and I want to be able to do things with them programmatically using an enum as a key.

The only way I can think of to do this is to have an externally linked initialization function for each "command" that is called by some other code to add a function pointer to a data structure. This sucks because then I have to declare these initialization functions in a header, define them in the individual files, and call them from somewhere else.

This method adds several lines of boiler plate for each "command," which is made worse because the boilerplate is spread across several files.

If it is possible, I'd like to have a single const array of function pointers to these static functions. Is there anything in the C99 standard that would allow me to do this?

The following code is a simplified representation of my problem, and some of it is definitely wrong, because I don't know how to do this or if it is even possible in C99.

#### Header included in all files

```
typedef enum
{
    EXAMPLE_ENUM_0
    EXAMPLE_ENUM_1
    EXAMPLE_ENUM_2
    EXAMPLE_ENUM_MAX_NUM_T,
} example_enum_t;

typedef void (*p_func_t)(void);
```

#### File 0

```
static void static_function_0(void)
{
    void * p_peripheral = 0x00000200;
    *p_peripheral = PERIPH_0_CONFIG;
}

extern int initialized_in_multiple_files[EXAMPLE_ENUM_MAX_NUM_T] = {
    [EXAMPLE_ENUM_0] = &static_function_0
};
```

#### File 1

```
static void static_function_1(void)
{
    void * p_peripheral = 0x00000300;
    *p_peripheral = PERIPH_1_CONFIG;
}

extern int initialized_in_multiple_files[EXAMPLE_ENUM_MAX_NUM_T] = {
    [EXAMPLE_ENUM_1] = &static_function_1
};
```

#### File 2

```
static void static_function_2(void)
{
    void * p_peripheral = 0x00000400;
    *p_peripheral = PERIPH_2_CONFIG;
}

extern int initialized_in_multiple_files[EXAMPLE_ENUM_MAX_NUM_T] = {
    [EXAMPLE_ENUM_2] = &static_function_2
};
```

#### File where I want to use all the function pointers

```
p_func_t initialized_in_multiple_files[EXAMPLE_ENUM_MAX_NUM_T] = {0U};

for (uint32_t index = 0U; index < EXAMPLE_ENUM_MAX_NUM_T; index += 1U)
{
    p_func_t p_func = initialized_in_multiple_files[index];
    if (NULL != p_func)
    {
        p_func();
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't see how that could work. Once it's initialized, it's initialized. When you add a new function, you need to update `example_enum_t`. Wouldn't it be better to then just update `initialized_in_multiple_files` and put the new function in it while you are editing that part of the code?

Comment: Unrelated: `index += 1U` is a cumbersome way to do `++index`.

Comment: Unfortunately no. Current linkers don't support this - so there's no way that it could be in the language.

Comment: @TedLyngmo no, it is not. It is more readable in many circumstances for example `char *c; /* ... */ *x += 1;`

Comment: Thanks to God there is no way of doing it your way. Add function which when called will do it for you. Much cleaner.

Comment: Use a factory whatever the imperative name is of that.  Auto-generate the tedious bits.

Comment: @0___________ Is this one of the circumstances where `index += 1U` is more readable than `++index`?

Comment: For beginners: *always*

Comment: A common solution to this is to write a script that creates a header file that merges all the individual files into the array initialization.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I dislike the increment and decrement operators, so I don't use them. In my opinion, they are unnecessary and cause confusion. Incrementing is not it's own operation, it is simply an addition. As an aside, my employer's style checker rejects those operators because prefix/postfix increment/decrement has caused expensive bugs for them in the past.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to use designated initializers to initialize parts of the same array in separate files?

There can be many declarations of the same object, but only one definition.  A declaration that initializes the object is a definition.  Designated initializers do not alter this.  Moreover, there is no partial initialization.  Any initializer for an object initializes the whole object.

> I'd like to have a single const array of function pointers to these static functions. Is there anything in the C99 standard that would allow me to do this?

No, not if the functions have internal linkage and are defined in separate files.  However, you can work around the `const`ness part by declaring a corresponding pointer to `const` elements in the header but *defining* the array itself non-`const`.  Code in the translation unit where it is defined could then pass it (decayed to a pointer) to various functions to fill in its elements, but code in other translation units, seeing its `const` declaration in the header, would not be able to alter its contents (at least, not without casting away the `const`ness).

Alternatively, if you give the functions external linkage then you could write one big initializer in the file of your choice.

Either way, you might be able to write a code generator to help you.  That could significantly reduce the amount of boilerplate code you have to maintain manually.

Comment: I think redeclaring non-const object as const is UB. The const and non-const variants of the same type are incompatible therefore there is no composite type for them.

Comment: Fair enough, @tstanisl.  I have revised the recommendation to now suggest an external pointer-to-const, instead of redeclaring the array itself `const`.  The pointer will serve the same purposes the array would do, except providing for computing the size occupied by the array or an equivalent.

Comment: I have decided to do an automated refactor to change the functions from internal to external linkage, and do one big initializer. It's not as tidy as I'd like, but I guess it keeps boilerplate to a minimum. Thanks!